# Can you enable additional functionality for "Run Command" under Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, user-interface

I want to have:

- checkbox "run as administrator"
- program name completion
- command history

in <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> dialog under Windows 7.

Is it possible such customization without any external tools. like http://www.technize.com/runmanager/ ?? I don't like installing a lot of tools for such small tasks but I think it is easy to run proper **.reg** file once...

But I already use http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/ to make working environment more natural for my needs.

Windows XP have command history in "Run command" dialog but it was disappear in Windows 7 (for my installation)...

Links:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_command

Answer (score 1):

I would assume Classic Shell uses the normal Shell Run dialog like the system does.

That dialog (and the underlying functionality) is provided by `shell32.dll`.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356270/how-to-programmatically-open-run-c) explains how to invoke it programmatically.

So, a solution would have to hook any call to that function to fully replace the functionality with an own dialog.

I guess writing such a software is not impossible, but I'm certain that the functionality you're looking for isn't already built into Windows. So I doubt you would be able to *just enable it* by running a `.reg` file.

Answer (score 0):

if, i understand you correct, you want to run programms from "Run command" and set alias for every exe file, you can create bat file which run every programm you need with name of alias, and set the directory with this file to PATH environment variable. I think it'll be work. If i 'not understand you correctly can you explain your question with more details please. Thanks

Comment: **program name completion** is not alias, it is completion )) Like <kbd>TAB</kbd> in GNU Bash...

Answer (score 0):

I have both history and completion, are you sure you don't have history in the dialogue? Have you removed it, then add it again! :)

To run as admin hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> instead of just enter in the search box (not run dialog).
That is, to run a command prompt: hit <kbd>Win</kbd> (and only Win), type `cmd` and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>

Comment: He uses [ClassicShell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/) and (maybe) doesn't even use these (great) features. :(

Comment: Sorry, I use http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/ and "Classic Start Menu" and Win+R. Anyway I need to run program that in my PATH env var instead of icons in "Program menu"...

Comment: Hmm OK, each to his/her own I guess. You are removing the best feature that was added in vista and later (hitting the win and just type what you want, program, command, document, web, whatever...). It's not jsut the programs from the menu. "cmd" works fine for example.